# IPE not compiling LaTeX

Tags: ipe

I had always been able to use Ipe without any problem but it randomly started showing this image and not compiling anything added with the math symbol. 
[image]

I've checked the command path and the LaTeX executable is there (it never moved). Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a way to get the TeX file? It's hard to find the bug without access to the code.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I believe I don't know how to get this file.

Comment: Does it run without the labels? Can you run pdflatex from the command line?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen pdflatex latex works just fine from the command line and I can compile LaTeX documents without any problem (I use TeXShop).

Comment: Try a new file with just one line. No labels, no other geometrical objects. Does it compile then?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Do you mean a normal TeX file? With a \begin{document} \end{document} and that's it?

Comment: I meant a new IPE file. Just a line in the IPE file. If this compiles without errors, the error probably has to do with the text labels in the file.

Comment: In the screenshot I can see labels with math notation. Change them and see if it compiles. I've never used IPE so I don't know if math mode syntax is supported in the labels.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen The porgram only compiles a document whenever one adds a mathematical expression or symbol. As for drawing lines and typing it works fine.

Comment: I finally uninstalled it and installed a previous version, ipe 7.2.7, which works fine. This all started (not immediately) after updating to Mac OS Catalina.